# Increase the performance in Django ORM

Tags: django, orm

```
contents = Content.objects.filter(   
    is_excluded=False
).prefetch_related('comments', 'likes', 'dislikes').order_by('-id').all()[:500]
result = [(v, len(v.comments.all())) for v in contents if len(v.likes.all()) -len(v.dislikes.all()) > 24][:7]
```

I want to return the content which has more than 25 like and 500 recently content.
This works, but is there other way to increase the performance?

Answer (score 4):

You can filter at the database side already. This will prevent making an extra query for the `.prefetch_related(…)` but will also limit the *bandwidth* used to transfer data:

```
from django.db.models import Count

contents = Content.objects.annotate(
    nlikes=Count('likes')
).filter(
    is_excluded=False,
    nlikes__gt=24
).order_by('-id')[:500]
```

This will thus obtain the 500 `Content`s with the highest primary key that have more than 24 likes.

You can for example filter the balance between `likes` and `dislikes` with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

contents = Content.objects.annotate(
    nlikes=Coalesce(Count('likes', distinct=True), Value(0))-Coalesce(Count('dislikes', distinct=True), Value(0))
).filter(
    is_excluded=False,
    nlikes__gt=24
).order_by('-id')[:500]
```

Here the [**`distinct=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct) is necessary, since there are two `JOIN`s, and without a uniquness filter, the two aggregates would thus act as *multipliers* of each other.

That being said, I'm not sure if it is a good idea to have two related models for likes and dislikes. Why not make one model (like `Thumb`), with a value `+1` for a like, and `-1` for a dislike. It makes the modeling simpeler, since then you can use a [**`Sum`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum) instead.

Comment: Thanks. But it's complicated because I use prefetch related and other code. I edit my code. Can you review this?

Comment: @HyeongJinKim: you can still use `.prefetch_related` on this queryset. But you do not *have* to do that for filtering purposes.